# How to create a kubernetes workload and expose it in same command line?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, workload

In a kubernetes cluster we can create a workload and expose it in two separate commands.

1. kubectl run deployment-name --image=imagename
2. kubectl expose deployment deployment-name [--port=port --type=type --name=name]

Could we do it in one command?

Comment: `kubectl apply -f` will apply arbitrarily many Kubernetes YAML objects from a single file or directory.  You can make sure that directory is checked into source control so the setup is repeatable.

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved by the below command. It will create a workload and also expose it in same time.

**kubectl run nginx-digital --image=nginx --expose=true --port=80**

The above command will create a deployment *nginx-digital* and also expose it with *ClusterIP* service with name *nginx-digital* at port *80*.

Comment: this does not create a deployment it creates a pod.